# How to add Content to Expended TableViewCell in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xib

I am new to Objective C and I am not able to add Image to Expended Table View Cell.
My code is:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        return 200.0; // Expanded height
    }
    return 63;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
        return 1;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates]; // tell the table you're about to start making changes

    if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
    } else {
        self.expandedIndexPath = indexPath;
        // hideview.hidden=NO;
    }
    [tableView endUpdates]; // tell the table you're done making your changes

}
```

I am able to expend the cell but unable for adding Image to expended table view cell.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Can you give me any example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use UIAlertController instead of UITableView.Show UITableView in UIAlertController.

Hear is a code how to show UITableView in UIAlertController.

```
 UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    CGRect rect;
    if (idarray.count < 4) {
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 160);
        [controller setPreferredContentSize:rect.size];

    }
    else if (idarray.count < 6){
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 300);
        [controller setPreferredContentSize:rect.size];
    }
    else if (idarray.count < 8){
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 200);
        [controller setPreferredContentSize:rect.size];

    }
    else {
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 250);
        [controller setPreferredContentSize:rect.size];
    }

    alert =
    [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Your Title"
                                        message:@""
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    TableName = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
    TableName.delegate = self;
    TableName.dataSource = self;
    [controller.view addSubview:TableName];
    [controller.view bringSubviewToFront:TableName];
    [controller.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [TableName setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [TableName setAllowsSelection:YES];

    [alert setValue:controller forKey:@"contentViewController"];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }];
    [alert addAction:cancelAction];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```